# How to parallelize a Python simulation script on a GPU with CUDA?

Tags: graphics-card, python, cuda

I want to test run some finite-difference time domain (FDTD) simulations using parallelization on a GPU and compare the speed to CPU-based simulation runs. This is basically my very first attempt at using GPU acceleration for scientific computing.

My system configuration:

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-4930K @ 3.40 GHz
GPU: Gigabte GeForce GTX 1650 OC LP 4.0 GB
RAM: 32.0 GB (16.0 GB usable)
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
```

This GPU has [896 CUDA cores](https://www.gigabyte.com/de/Graphics-Card/GV-N1650OC-4GL/sp#sp) and [compute capability 7.5](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-enabled-geforce-1650/81010), so I'm expecting a significant acceleration when compared to running my simulation on "only" 12 CPU cores.

The simulation script uses the [`fdtd`](https://github.com/flaport/fdtd) simulation package and I'm using Jupyter notebooks for convenience. If you're interested in some actual code reference, I can recommend taking a look at the short example scripts on the `fdtd` GitHub page.

I've installed the CUDA ToolKit version 10.2 as this appears to be the last version with Windows 7 support. Version 11.0+ appears to support Windows 10+ only, at least according to the [download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) (can anyone confirm this?).

I've also installed `torch` + `torchvision` + `torchaudio`, simply because [PyTorch includes these packages](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) during installation procedure. However, I got stuck when trying to install the *Python* CUDA ToolKit as it [seems to require](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pip-wheels-installation-linux) another package called `nvidia-pyindex`, [which is not available for Windows](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow/issues/12#issuecomment-754086215). Moreover, I'm confused by the PyTorch installation command for CUDA 10.2 which says *`"CUDA-10.2 PyTorch builds are no longer available for Windows, please use CUDA-11.6"`*, especially since they [clearly state](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#supported-windows-distributions):

> Supported Windows Distributions
>
> PyTorch is supported on the following Windows distributions:
>
> **Windows 7** and greater; Windows 10 or greater recommended.
> Windows Server 2008 r2 and greater

In the Python interpreter, I'm getting

```
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
```

and trying to set the CUDA backend in the simulation package returns

```
import fdtd

fdtd.set_backend("torch.cuda.float64")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 35>()
     31 display(HTML("<style>.container {width:100% !important;}</style>"))
     33 #fdtd.set_backend("numpy")
     34 #fdtd.set_backend("torch.float64")
---> 35 fdtd.set_backend("torch.cuda.float64")

File C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\fdtd\backend.py:376, in set_backend(name)
    374     raise RuntimeError("Torch backend is not available. Is PyTorch installed?")
    375 if name.startswith("torch.cuda") and not TORCH_CUDA_AVAILABLE:
--> 376     raise RuntimeError(
    377         "Torch cuda backend is not available.\n"
    378         "Do you have a GPU on your computer?\n"
    379         "Is PyTorch with cuda support installed?"
    380     )
    382 if name.count(".") == 0:
    383     dtype, device = "float64", "cpu"

RuntimeError: Torch cuda backend is not available.
Do you have a GPU on your computer?
Is PyTorch with cuda support installed?
```

How should I progress from here?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be at an impasse.

Your tools clearly have a chain of dependencies that require a newer version of Windows.

Python CUDA toolkit wants CUDA >= 11.6
You have installed a previous version of CUDA (10.2)

You should install CUDA 11.6. If it is not supported on Windows 7 (which is why you are trying to use 10.2) then you need to upgrade to a newer version of Windows and then an updated version of CUDA.

Windows 7 has been out of support since January 14, 2020. It might be a good workhorse for older tools that haven't been updated but clinging to it while the world moves on around you is not worth the pain or effort.